# git (source tree) how to recover unstaged files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I committed and pushed some code that did not work, which I thought would be a good opportunity to learn how to rollback to a previous commit/pull.

I used **reset master to this commit** which seemed to work but then I noticed the non-working commit was still there and it said I was 1 behind the most up-to date commit (the commit containing the code that did not work).

I then did something that may have been completely stupid, I used the **remove** button for the commit I was behind (the earlier code I did not want). After this, the commit is still there but now my uncommitted changes list is just showing a deletion of a file from the commit I wanted to lose.

It seems I've lost all my unstaged files I have been working on all day. How can I get these back and lose the useless commit that I pushed earlier?

Thank you for your time and input.

Comment: The most important question is did you push your commit?  If so, are there other users?  If yes to both of these, assume it's set in stone.

Comment: @lassombra Yes the original commit was pushed with one file change. My worry is that there were multiple file changes waiting in unstaged files that have disappeared after the above changes, they have completely dissapeared after using the remove button. I thought the remove button would only remove the commit that I originally pushed.

Comment: are there other users involved (other important question)?

Remove removes files from your file system, not git.  Once they're in a commit, they're in there unless you do history rewrites which no system is going to make easy to do.

Comment: There is one other user yes. So how would I recover the unstaged files that have disappeared? Thanks @lassombra

Comment: Unfortunately, as I said, git remove takes files out of your file system.  If they were tracked files, you can reset your working directory and get back to the state of your last commit, but you simply cannot recover work you have done that git didn't know about after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, I'd recommend reading up on git terms and what different operations actually mean: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2.

A good surface cheat sheet can be found at http://www.ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html  Now to get to what you are dealing with.

Remove doesn't remove things from git, in fact, it does exactly what the rm command does on the command line in unix.  It removes them from your file system.  If you rm files that you hadn't staged, they are just plain gone.

Unfortunately, I can't help you with getting back files you deleted.  Look into your OS's recovery tools if you can, but don't hold your breath unless you have a delete cache of some sort (recycle bin on windows).

Revert allows you to make an inverse commit that puts everything back as if you had never made the original commit, but leaves the original in history so you can always see what happened.  Despite what people tend to expect, this doesn't eliminate the commit, but actually creates a new one.  This is the best option if you are going to be touching stuff that's already been pushed.

Reset changes one of the various states in your git process to allow you to change what you are doing.  A soft reset changes just the HEAD pointer that you are pointing at.  The command `git reset --soft` will change your HEAD pointer to whatever commit you provide it (by default HEAD accomplishing nothing).  The command `git reset` will change your HEAD and your staging area to match a given commit (by default HEAD so it just unstages everything).  The command `git reset --hard` will reset HEAD, staging area (aka index) and working directory to match a given commit (again, by default HEAD so you go back to a completely clean environment as if you hadn't done anything since last commit).

If you want to remove a commit completely, that is called resetting the head.  Technically the commit itself never goes away, but you can make it so it's unreachable through normal means, and effectively take it out of project history.  A word of caution: this should **NEVER** be done on pushed commits with downstream users.  The big question is often, how much do you hate your downstream as the only safe option for them is to re-clone blowing away all of their own work after you do this.

The process would be to `git reset --hard HEAD` taking your entire environment to the state of the last commit.  Then you want to `reset --soft HEAD^` which changes the HEAD (what commit you're working off of) to one previous.  This leaves you in the state just before you hit commit, with all of your staged changes still staged.  At this point, you can discard your changes with `git reset --hard HEAD`, you can unstage everything with `git reset HEAD` And finally you can build another commit and move forward.

For a more indepth look at changing history, and why it's basically not allowed after it's been pushed you can look here: http://justinhileman.info/article/changing-history/ there is even a very nice flowchart with command references at the end of the article.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give me some very useful guides and pointers I can learn from.

Comment: @RubyMax No problem.  I'm sorry that your code is gone.  I can really empathize with that as I had a script I was writing last week literally delete itself, moments before I was going to stage it to git!